# change the central frequency of a wavelet

Tags: wavelet

I am using the discrete meyer wavelet in MATLAB for time series decomposition. I would like to change the central frequency of this wavelet but I do not know if this is possible or if I would need to design a new wavelet.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB documentation indicates that discretization of the continuous and infinite-support Meyer wavelet is done simply by regular sampling. I doubt that there are any unwanted consequences if you sample it over a longer interval than the nominal -8 to 8 effective support, to have a different central frequency.

The standard values for the first two parameters to `meyer(LB,UB,N)` are `LB` = -8, `UB` = 8, defining the interval to be covered by sampling. Multiply those parameters by the same factor by which you want to multiply the central frequency. If factor < 1, you should double `LB` and `UB` to ensure that you sample the whole effective support of the Meyer wavelet and scaling functions. Then you will find your wanted frequency on the next scale level.